# need clearty on solutions-ios-push-notification

Tags: android, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

Does code provided in "https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/solutions-ios-push-notification-sample-backend-java" support to send push notification on iOS device as well as Android device.

Answer (score 0):

The code provided in the link you supplied supports **only** push notifications on iOS devices (Apple Push Notifications). It uses the `JavaPNS` library for the actual communication with Apple's APNS servers.

Comment: Do we have any other API that can support both the platform iOS and Android..??

Comment: On the link provided below, I'm not able to understand the 5th point as I'm very new in iOS development and using Xcode. can any body elaborate it 5th point of this implementation.
  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/consume_ios